# How to get the rails.vim-command :Rview working with .js.erb-views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, command, rails.vim

I want Rview to jump to .js.erb-views as well.

It always says "Can't find file "app/views/examples/foo".

The help says:

> *rails-template-types* 
>   Commands like :Rview use a hardwired list of
>   extensions (erb, rjs, etc.) when searching for files.  In order to
>   facilitate working with non-standard template types, several popular
>   extensions are featured in this list, including haml, liquid, and mab
>   (markaby).  These extensions will disappear once a related
>   configuration option is added to rails.vim.

Since the view ends with .erb, i would suggest it should work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, I just checked in my vim and it works fine. I use [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus), but I think that the standard vim + rails.vim should work well.
Maybe you need to update rails.vim?
And you can tell the sequence of your actions: the current file, typed commands, etc.

Comment: I just had to update. I did not consider updating, since my version was just 1 1/2 month old. Never mind, thanks for the answer.